# Error when TextFiled Input in lua is empty?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

The problem is when txt.text is empty I get error.

```
--input text 
local txt = native.newTextField(160,100,300,50)
--button press to get answer 
local btn = display.newRect(160,300,120,40)
--label text to show answer
local label = display.newText("answer",160,200)

txt.inputType = "number"

function doit(e)
    -- Currency exchange (USD to any country)
    label.text = txt.text * 2
    -- when txt.text == empty I get error
end

btn:addEventListener("tap",doit)
```

I tried to use `if else` but same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add proper `if` statement. Try with:

```
function doit (e)
    if tonumber(txt.text) then
        label.text = tonumber(txt.text) * 2
    end
end
```

Rest of the code remains the same.